# iOS: Class method added by class_addMethod can't be used by NSInvocation

Tags: ios, runtime, selector, class-method, nsinvocation

I add a class method to a class using runtime feature, but this method can't be used by **NSInvocation**. My code is as this:

```
id metaClass = object_getClass((id)protocolClass);
IMP prevImp = class_replaceMethod(metaClass, @selector(xxx), imp, NULL);

const char *selectorName = sel_getName(@selector(xxx));
char newSelectorName[strlen(selectorName) + 10];
strcpy(newSelectorName, "ORIGIN");
strcat(newSelectorName, selectorName);
SEL newSelector = sel_getUid(newSelectorName);
if(!class_respondsToSelector(metaClass, newSelector)) {
    class_addMethod(metaClass, newSelector, prevImp, NULL);
}

NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:
                            [protocolClass methodSignatureForSelector:newSelector]];
```

The invocation creating syntax crash as:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:]: type signature is empty.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x07c251e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x079a48e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x07c13ce4 +[NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:] + 1172
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x07cc22e9 +[NSObject(NSObject) methodSignatureForSelector:] + 73
        ......
)
```

Any explanation? The reason I need to use **NSInvocation** is because I want the return value  of the selector, any other methods?

Comment: If you know the signature of this selector (its return type and what kind of parameters it takes), you can form the method signature manually.

Comment: Also use the debugger to make sure you're getting values throughout. Maybe `newSelector` is nil, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the signature string of the method as the 4th argument of `class_addMethod`. You are passing `NULL`.